# Spring mongodb $avg return null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have my collection(mongodb) and i want to get from one field(array) the avg. Collection is like:

```
"rate" : [
    {
        "general_rate" : 2,
        "comment" : "Bad"
    }
]
```

I need the avg of general_rate. My problem comes when field rate is null. For that reason i use $ifnull operator to check and add in rate the general_rate :0. My implementation of all this is:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            unrate(),
            unwind("rate"),
            group("id").first("name").as("name").avg("$rate.general_rate").as("rate"),
            project("rate","name").and("_id").previousOperation()
    );

private CustomGroupOperation unrate(){
    DBObject myProject = (DBObject)new BasicDBObject(
            "$project", new BasicDBObject(
            "name","$name").append(
            "rate", new BasicDBObject(
            "$ifNull", new Object[]{
            "$rate", new Object[]{
                    "general_rate", 0
            }
    })
    ));

    return new CustomGroupOperation(myProject);
}
```

But avg("rate.general_rate") returns null when a null rate field appears. Any solution?

Comment: do you have any documents when this array is not present?

Comment: No, but with $ifNull check didn't supposed that a new field: general_rate will creating?

Comment: in other words we need to check for existence `$exists`, if the firld value will be null like `rate:null` it will be skipped, but when ther will be no field - then mongo throws exception - to check that try to execute same query in mongo shell or robomongo.